# CSS3 triangle with bottom line

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Is it possible to draw a below mentioned object as mentioned below by using **CSS3**??

[image]

(triangle at the middle,Left and right side of the triangle have line at the bottom).

Please advice me.

Comment: Are these carat (^) and hyphen (-) symbols? Then **--^--** it can be write without CSS. Can you please explain more?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JaMH9/2/ look at this for tringle using css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.arrow {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #FF0000;
    border-left: 16px dotted transparent;
    border-right: 16px dotted transparent;
    left: 0px;
    top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.line {
    width: 200px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

Not exactly the same in dimension but you can edit and create like that.

Edit:
For your new shape, add the below in CSS and HTML:

CSS:

```
.fill {
    position: relative;
    left: -14px;
    top: 2px;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 14px dotted transparent;
    border-right: 14px dotted transparent;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="arrow">
    <div class="fill"></div>
</div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you need the background behind the triangle to be transparent:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="line-separator">
    <div class="side-line"> </div>
    <div class="triangle"> </div>
    <div class="side-line"> </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.side-line {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 20%;
}

.triangle {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 7px;
    width: 7px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: center center;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-right: -3px;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

**Live demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/85saaphw/